# Activity is not assigned to Android.app.Activity Manifest XML

Tags: java, android, android-activity, manifest

I am having some trouble with the fragment in Android Studio. So basically this is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
final Context context = this;

ViewPager Tab;
TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                  android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab selected show respected fragment view
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };

    // Add New Tab
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Feedback")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("History Log")
            .setTabListener(tabListener));


}
}
```

And then my another class which is one of the tab code:

```
public class FeedbackMain extends Fragment {
View feedbackMainView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    feedbackMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_feedback_main,
            container, false);

    return feedbackMainView;
}
}
```

And then my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedbackMain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback_main" >
    </activity>
```

However, I am getting red lines under .FeedbackMain and the error message is:

```
.FeedbackMain is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'
```

I was wondering why is it so? It was working fine with Android development tools but then when I switched to Android Studio, this happens.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

xml file for mainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

style.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you only declare activities in manifest file, not fragments.
So remove this line from manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name=".FeedbackMain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback_main" >
    </activity>
```

Secondly, if you want to use actionbar, you class should extend ActionBarActivity not FragmentActivity. so change your mainactivity from

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

then make sure you call `getSupportActionBar()` if you are using support library

EDIT:

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() { 
@Override 
public void onTabReselected( 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0, 
FragmentTransaction arg1) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 

@Override 
public void onTabSelected( 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0, 
FragmentTransaction arg1) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 

@Override 
public void onTabUnselected( 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0, 
FragmentTransaction arg1) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 
};
```

Comment: After I changed it there is another error message at the ActionBar.TabListener. The error message as Class anonymous class derived from TabListener must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onTabSelected

Comment: I have to remove the Override as there are some red line highlighted underneath

Comment: are you using supprort library?

Comment: Sorry but how do I check? Is it the one under gradle? dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

Comment: yes, did you import these in your activity?
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;

Comment: Yeah these are my imports: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;

Comment: also this one
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;

Comment: Nope, the same error message still there. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, i got the error, in you code change android.app.ActionBar.Tab to just Tab like
public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, to
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78932/discussion-between-durga-mohan-and-denise).

Answer (score 3):

this error is caused because `FeedBackMain` is declared as `Activity` not as a `Fragment`

```
 <activity
        android:name=".FeedbackMain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback_main" >
    </activity>
```

if you really want use it as `Activity` Change

```
public class FeedbackMain extends Fragment {
```

to

```
public class FeedbackMain extends FragmentActivity {
```

but if you want use it as `Fragment` just delete the declaration inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

use `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` instead of `getActionBar()`

You need some method implementations:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

    public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                              android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected show respected fragment view
        Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
            FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
            FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
            FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: I tried to changed it just now but it still crashed

Comment: ok Denise you want to use it as a fragment delete the declaration inside the AndroidManifest.xml and keep extending as a Fragment.

Comment: Yeah I deleted already but then it gives me an error message of null pointer exception at actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: thats another issue, in MainActivity add import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
and extend from ActionBarActivity :
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
use "actionBar =  getSupportActionBar();" instead of getActionBar()

Comment: After I changed it there is another error message at the ActionBar.TabListener. The error message as Class anonymous class derived from TabListener must either be declared abstrct

Comment: I can help you Denise, but i think you have more than one issue do you  have a link for the complete code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78931/discussion-between-denise-and-elenasys).

Comment: Well I have added the methods that you need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<activity
    android:name=".FeedbackMain"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback_main" >
</activity>
```

from your Manifest file. Since FeebackMain is a Fragment and not an Activity, you don't need to define it inside your Manifest.

Comment: But when I removed it, it tells me null pointer exception at this line: actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: Add `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` inside your MainActivity.java and see if it works.

Comment: Alright, go inside your res>values folder and post the styles.xml file here.

Comment: Hey any ideas? I am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

`FeedbackMain` is a `Fragment`, not an `Activity`. You don't have to declare it in your Manifest file. I don't know why that behavior changed when you switched to Android Studio, but that is what it is complaining about.

Comment: But when I removed it, it tells me null pointer exception at this line: actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: So `actionBar` is null, which means `getActionBar()` returns null. Can you add the layout xml file of your fragment and activity to your post?

Comment: I edited the post already. Basically the fragment layout is just linear layout with a lot of textview

Comment: Checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html) tutorial on setting up the `ActionBar`. Your activity need to extend `ActionBarActivity`, for example. This tutorial (and the next steps) should help you out.

Comment: Alright but is there any other way to fix this if I wanted to stick with my code?

Comment: You have to remove the `ActionBar` then.

Comment: But I thought without the action bar, there will be no title for the tab?