# Error creating tabs

Tags: java, android, view, scrollable

What does `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference` meant? I tried many solution but no one can solve my problem.

**Tab.java**

```
package com.example.project.project;
     import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class Tab extends FragmentActivity {
         ViewPager Tab;
         TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
         ActionBar actionBar;

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

             TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


             Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

             Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                     new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                             actionBar = getActionBar();
                             actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                     });

             Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);

             actionBar = getActionBar();

             //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
             actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
             ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

                 public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                             FragmentTransaction ft) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tab selected", 2000).show();

               }

                 @Override
                 public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                     Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                             FragmentTransaction ft) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }};
             //Add New Tabs
             actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Information").setTabListener(tabListener));
             actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Work Force").setTabListener(tabListener));
             actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Work Details").setTabListener(tabListener));

         }




     }
```

**TabPagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.project.project;

        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

   @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:

                return new Information();

            case 1:

                return new WorkDetailsTable();
        }
        return null ;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3; //No of Tabs you can give your number of tabs
    }


}
```

**Tab1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project.project" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WorkDetailsTable" android:screenOrientation="landscape"  />
        <activity android:name="Information"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Error**

```
10-04 11:11:07.492    2146-2146/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 2146
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.Tab}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

And in  my Mainfest.xml, the compiler said

```
<activity android:name=".WorkDetailsTable" android:screenOrientation="landscape"  />
        <activity android:name="Information"/>
```

is not assignable to android.app....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this lines:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```

With:

```
actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) mActivity).getSupportActionBar();
```

And add this on top of onCreate()

```
Activity mActivity = (Activity) this;
```

And start activity with this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityClassName"
        android:label="YourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="package.name.YOURACTIVITYCLASSNAME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

This is listener:

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tab selected", 2000).show();

        }

    }
```

Refer to this: [FragmentActivity vs Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318518/android-activity-vs-fragmentactivity)

> Also remember to use Activity if you are using android.app.Fragment; use FragmentActivity if you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Never attach a android.support.v4.app.Fragment to an android.app.Activity, as this will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see who was FragmentActivity give me a moment and I work out

Comment: After trying your method and  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; , I get this ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){ must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method...

Comment: I add the new listener :D enjoy

Comment: Thanks....can you help me figuring out my problem in AndroidMainfest.xml? It said I not assignable to android.app.Activity

Comment: ok, I have removed these from mainfest.xml and use your code. But after I changed it there is another error message at the ActionBar.TabListener. The error message as Class anonymous class derived from TabListener must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onTabSelected  and  the Override as there are some red line highlighted underneath

Comment: Have you use my code of TabListener? Because this error show when onTabSelected was not implemented...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91299/discussion-between-hoo-and-michele-lacorte).

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
 actionBar = getActionBar();
```

with

```
 actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar();
```

where

```
Activity activity = (Activity) this;
```

Comment: variable activity is accessed from within inner calss,need to be declared final

Comment: Please decare activity at the top with viewPager, ActionBar etc, else try making it final Activity actvity = (Activity) this

Comment: After trying your method and import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; , I get this ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){ must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method..

Comment: then please implement the abstract method

Comment: By the way you are using a deprecated way of implementing tabs which might cause problems in future. This is the correct and recommended way. http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: Thanks....can you help me figuring out my problem in AndroidMainfest.xml? It said I not assignable to android.app.Activity ....Did I miss out something?

Comment: Can you please quote the exact error? In any case I think this will definitely help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486389/activity-is-not-assigned-to-android-app-activity-manifest-xml  :-)

Comment: It totally frustrating! I think I facing the same problem like him. Sadly , some comment had moved to chat discussion and I still stuck.

Comment: There is another error message at the ActionBar.TabListener. The error message as Class anonymous class derived from TabListener must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onTabSelected and the Override as there are some red line highlighted underneath

Comment: just implement the method as it is asking, and it would be fine.

Comment: just paste the 3 tab methods as shown by Michael in the other answer and it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91298/discussion-between-hoo-and-varunkr).

Comment: Thanks for your help...but I only can accept one answer. Between, you both are awesome :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Actionbar has to be replaced with toolbar now, all you need to do is include a toolbar in your xml files. I used the appcompact library toolbar, for this you may have to add support library in your gradle file
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

Add follwing toolbar to xml file 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


Don't forget to inherit your activity from Appcompactactivity, you may use your own toolbar, finally access the toolbaar in activity
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```